# Java code could not read the file located on the Client machine

Tags: file, file-upload

I am using a struts application.
I want to upload a file in JSP and read the contents of that file in the Java.

Case 1:
I deployed this application.war in my local tomcat server, and ran the app, it works fine. (Local machine OS is windows)

Case 2:
When I deployed this application.war in the tomcat server on Unix machine, and ran, it gives the error "No such file or directory". it could not read file stored on my local machine when ran on the unix machine.
Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot interact with the client machine from your server.

Instead, you need to use an HTML file upload control, and read the file contents that get POSTed back to the server.

Comment: Thanks Slaks. I am actually using a HTML file upload control. I could upload the file but on the server side Java file I read the contents of the file. It gives No such file exists error.